# Updating varchar column over linked server with parameterized query causes remote scan and cursorfetch

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I'm issuing a fairly simple update of single **varchar** column against a remote linked server. E.g.:

```
UPDATE Hydrogen.CRM.dbo.Customers
SET EyeColor = 'Blue'
WHERE CustomerID = 619
```

And that works fine when is written as an *ad-hoc* query:

[image]

### Parameterized Queries Bad

When we do what we're supposed to do, and have our `SqlCommand` issue it as a *parameterized-query*, the SQL ends up being:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [Hydrogen].[CRM].[dbo].[Customers] 
SET [EyeColor] = @P1 
WHERE [CustomerID] = @P5', 
N'@P1 varchar(4),@P5 bigint',
'Blue',619
```

The query ends up performing a **Remote Scan** against the linked server:

[image]

It creates a cursor on the linked server, and takes about 35 seconds to pull back **1.2M rows** to the local server through a series of hundreds of `sp_cursorfetch`

Why, in the world, would the local SQL Server optimizer ever decide to pull back all 1.2M rows to the local server in order to update anything?

### It only fails on varchar columns

If i update *int* fields, it works fine.

But this column is `varchar` - and it fails.

I tried other parameterizing the column as `nvarchar`, and it's still bad.

Every answer i've seen actually are questions:

- *"is the collation the same?"*
- *"What if you change the column type?"*
- *"Have you tried OPENQUERY?"*
- *"Does the login have `sysadmin` role on the linked server?"*

I already have my workaround: parameterized queries bad - use ad-hoc queries.

I was hoping for an *explanation* of the thing that makes no sense. And hopefully if we have an explanation we can fix it - rather than workaround it.

### Bonus Reading

- Stackoverflow: [Remote Query is slow when using variables vs literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31212087/12597)
- Stackoverflow: [Slow query when connecting to linked server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4214146/12597)
- [SQL Server update query on linked server causing remote scan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/36893/2758)
- Stackoverflow: [Parameter in linked-server query is converted from varchar to nvarchar, causing index scan and bad performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60109780/12597)
- [Performance Issues when Updating Data with a SQL Server Linked Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4428/performance-issues-when-updating-data-with-a-sql-server-linked-server/)
- [Update statements causing lots of calls to sp_cursorfetch?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c216ecd4-dbc9-49ba-8b47-48a93b85e783/update-statements-causing-lots-of-calls-to-spcursorfetch?forum=transactsql)
- [Remote Scan on Linked Server - Fast SELECT/Slow UPDATE](https://forums.databasejournal.com/showthread.php?14311-Remote-Scan-on-Linked-Server-Fast-SELECT-Slow-UPDATE)

*"Too localized, unlikely to help others." Gives 7 links of other people having the issue. I hate people.*

Comment: It doesn't reproduce for me in other environments. So we're left trying to imagine why a database server would ever issue a **"Remote Scan"**

Comment: Unfortunately I can't even reproduce it myself in a lab.

Comment: `HYDROGEN` is [a server name,](https://web.archive.org/web/20090801103712/http://serverfault.com/questions/45734/the-coolest-server-names/45841#45841), which is running an instance of SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

I talk a little about [the remote join hint here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2765/revisit-your-use-of-the-sql-server-remote-join-hint/), people can speculate but if they can't reproduce it's pretty tough to give you an *answer*.

In the meantime, you can use `sp_executesql` in a slightly different way to take away SQL Server's choices between bringing any data between the servers:

```
EXEC [Hydrogen].[CRM].sys.sp_executesql 
  N'UPDATE [dbo].[Customers]  SET [EyeColor] = @P1  
    WHERE [CustomerID] = @P5',  
  N'@P1 varchar(4),@P5 bigint', 
  'Blue',
  619;
```

Comment: The query isn't generated by me directly; it's the SqlClient's parameterized query that generates the pseudo-call to `sp_executesql`. My workaround of abandoning parameters also works as a workaround.